# PHP input type file field being submitted, file isnt

Tags: php, jquery, forms, file-upload

I have the following form.

```
<form action="picture.php" method="POST" class="pic_form">
<span class="picture_box">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="pic_upload" class="picture_upload_input" />
<p class="upload_info">Only file types of the extensions gif, jpg, png and svg are allowed. The maximum file size is 15mb. If your file is larger than 15mb, it will not upload.</p>
</span>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>" />
<input type="button" name="upload_button" value="Upload" class="upload_button" />
</form>
```

I validate that the file is set and that it's of the correct type and size using jQuery. When I submit this form (using jQuery), the field is posted

```
$_POST['pic_upload']
```

This returns true.

However, the file itself isn't posted

```
$_FILES['custom_pic_upload']
```

This returns false and

```
var_dump($_FILES['custom_pic_upload']);
```

returns null.

How do I make the file itself upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form needs the attribute `enctype`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form.

> multipart/form-data: The value used for an  element with the type attribute set to "file".

```
<form action="picture.php" method="POST" class="pic_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<span class="picture_box">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="pic_upload" class="picture_upload_input" />
<p class="upload_info">Only file types of the extensions gif, jpg, png and svg are allowed. The maximum file size is 15mb. If your file is larger than 15mb, it will not upload.</p>
</span>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="upload_button" value="Upload" class="upload_button" />
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$('.upload_button').click(function(){ 
    var upload_ver_val = $('.picture_upload_input').val(); 
    if (upload_ver_val == '') { 
        alert("Please upload an image!");
        return false;
    } else {
        var ext = $('.picture_upload_input').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(); 
        if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg','svg']) == -1) {
            alert('Only file types of the extensions; gif, jpg, png and svg are allowed!');
            return false;
        } else { 
            $('.prof_pic_form').submit(); 
        } 
    } 
});
</script>
```

Other threads on the topic and tutorial.

[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Also the name of the PHP value will be the `name` attribute, not the `class`, so look for it with `pic_upload`.

Comment: Ok, I don't have that problem anymore, but now, apparently if (isset($_POST['pic_upload'])) returns false

Comment: Are other POST values being submitted? `print_r($_POST);`.

Comment: Can you post how the form is being submitted?

Comment: $('.upload_button').click(function(){
 var upload_ver_val = $('.picture_upload_input').val();
  if (upload_ver_val == '') {
   alert("Please upload an image!");
  } else {
   var ext = $('.picture_upload_input').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg','svg']) == -1) {
    alert('Only file types of the extensions; gif, jpg, png and svg are allowed!');
} else {
 $('.prof_pic_form').submit();
  }
  }
});

Comment: this does correctly validate the file and submit the form

Comment: Updated with code that works locally for me. Doh, forgot to click save, 1 sec.